# My family and relatives

Tags: story

I have a strange family, we’re quite simple with only two byfeet, or something like that. My relatives are relatively confusing, but people just call them ‘complicated’. I don’t play sports, but I get swapped out for more accurate people I don’t mean anything bad, but people always say I’m plotting something or the other. What am I, my family, and my relatives?

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> A scatter plot or a graph?

I have a strange family, we’re quite simple with only two byfeet, or something like that.

> Your family are a set of different graphs on a Cartesian grid; the two byfeet are the x and y axes.

My relatives are relatively confusing, but people just call them ‘complicated’.

> Your relatives are graphs on a *complex* plane; they still have two axes, but one axis is the reals and one is the imaginary numbers. Complicated refers to complex numbers.

I don’t play sports, but I get swapped out for more accurate people

> Graphical solutions to mathematical problems might get swapped out for more accurate, analytical solutions to those problems.

I don’t mean anything bad, but people always say I’m plotting something or the other.

> You are a line graph or a scatter plot, then, since you're *plotting* things.

What am I, my family, and my relatives?

> I'd guess you are a line graph or scatter plot, your family is the set of all graphs on a Cartesian 2-D plane, and your relatives are the set of all graphs on the complex plane.

Comment: Wow that’s an interesting answer! You are close, but not yet there.